# Why this postfix input calculator in c using stack of array doesn;t work?

Tags: arrays, c, stack, postfix-notation

I am learning data structures and as I go through I needed to make a postfix input calculator in c.I wanted to make it using stack and stack of array.I wrote some code but it is not giving output instead it gives the first word i input in it.If I dont take input and give value in declaration of string this works but if I ask for input then it doesnt work.And i also tried to print strlength after the scanf it even if my input is 17 length it only prints 1.scan f is not working correctly or strlen is not working correctly.My code is :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stack_forpostfix.h"

int postfix(char *exp);
int isoperator1(char b);
int isnumericdigit1(char c);
int doevaluation(int oper1,char optr,int oper2);

int main(){
    char *exp1;
    int a;
    printf("Enter the postfix expresssion\n");/*if we dont ask and put input in declaration the code works perfect,because if we ask the strlen is not working*/
    scanf("%s",exp1);       //2 3 * 5 4 * + 9 -
    printf(" , %d , ",strlen(exp1));
    a=postfix(exp1);
    printf("%d\n",a);
}

int postfix(char *exp){
   
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(exp);i++){
        if(exp[i]==' ' || exp[i]==','){
            continue;
        }
        else if(isoperator1(exp[i])){
            int op2=gettop();
            pop();
            int op1=gettop();
            pop();
            int result=doevaluation(op1,exp[i],op2);
            push(result);
        }

        else if(isnumericdigit1(exp[i])){
            int oper=0;

            while(i<strlen(exp) && isnumericdigit1(exp[i])){
                oper=(oper*10)+(exp[i]-'0');
                i++;
            }  //since i++ is there if no i-- exp[i] will escape one further
            i--;
            push(oper); 
        }
    }
    return gettop();    
}

int isnumericdigit1(char c){
    if (c>='0' && c<='9'){
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}

int isoperator1(char b){
    if(b=='+'||b=='-'||b=='*'||b=='/'){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int doevaluation(int oper1,char optr,int oper2){

    if(optr=='+'){
        return oper1+oper2;
    }else if (optr=='-'){
        return oper1-oper2;
    }else if (optr=='*'){
        return oper1*oper2;
    }else if (optr=='/'){
        return oper1/oper2;
    }else {
        printf("not valid");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

And my header file(stack_forpostfix.h) code is :-

```
#ifndef stackyfix
#define stackyfix

#define maxsize 111


int a[maxsize];
int top=-1;

void push(int r){
    top++;
    a[top]=r;
}

void pop(){
    top--;
}

int gettop(){
    return a[top];
}
#endif
```

Comment: Don't put functions in a header file (unless they're inlines).  Header files contain declarations.  The functions go in the corresponding `.c` file.

Comment: Both of `scanf()` and `strlen()` are working perfectly as they told. You are so (un)lucky that yor invokation of *undefined behavior* (using indeterminate value of uninitialized variable) didn't lead to crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In infix to postfix function, in place of str[i]=gettop(); there should be str[j]=gettop() so the expression entered inside the brackets can be pprocessed. Also add this piece of code after fgets to remove the '\n' that fgets may append.

```
fgets(b,sizeof(b),stdin);    

for(int i=0;b[i]!='\0';i++){ // removes \n added by fgets
        if(b[i]=='\0'){
            if(b[i-1]=='\n'){
                b[i-1]='\0';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have posted an *identical* answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69040826/10871073). Please refrain from doing this.

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%s",exp1);
```

Will stop reading when it encountered to whitespace characters.
You should use `fgets()` instead.

Also, do not forget to allocate buffer for reading the expression.

```
char exp1[102400]; // believing that huge expression won't come
fgets(exp1, sizeof(exp1), stdin);
```

Also note that

```
printf(" , %d , ",strlen(exp1));
```

will invoke *undefined behavior* for type mismatch: `%d` expects `int` while `strlen()` returns `size_t`.
The format type specifier to print `size_t` is `%zu`.
If your environment doesn't support `%zu`, you should cast the return value to `int` before passing it to `%d`.

Comment: Also worth noting that if the OP is learning on an embedded system, then they should adjust the size of the buffer to fit their data and available memory accordingly. Buffers as small as 250 bytes can exceed available memory on many. There are many classes being taught with microcontrollers today.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! MikeCAT  !! . But why doesnt char *exp1 doesnt works? and what is %zu?