# Why is this Calculator program using stack not working? It gives some undefined behaviour ,why?

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

I tried to make a calculator using stack but it works partially (that is, sometimes when I insert larger number the answer is wrong but for small numbers generally correct).I don't know may be there is some undefined behaviour in my code (and also some charachter is getting swapped somewhere see I have mentioned it in my code comment). What is wrong in it.
My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "stackforcalc.h"

int isOperand(char b){
    if(b>='0' && b<='9'){
        return 1;
    }else{  
    return 0;
    }
}

int isOperator(char b){
    if(b=='+' || b=='-' || b=='*' || b=='/'){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int getwt(char b){
    int g=-1;
    switch (b)
    {
    case '+':
    case '-':
    g=1;
    break;
    case '/':
    case '*':
    g=28787868;
    break;
    }
    return g;
}


int higherprecedence(char a,char b){
    int c=getwt(a);
    int d=getwt(b);
    return (c>=d)?1:0;
}

int infToPost(char *b,char *str){
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(b);i++){
        if(b[i]== ' ' || b[i]== ',' ){
            continue;
        }

        else if(isOperator(b[i])){
            str[j]=' ';
            j++;
            while(!empty() && gettop() != '(' && higherprecedence(gettop(),b[i])){
                str[j]=gettop();
                j++;
                pop();
            }
            push(b[i]);
        }

        else if(isOperand(b[i])){
            str[j]=b[i];
            j++;
        }

        else if(b[i]=='('){
            push(b[i]);
        }

        else if(b[i] ==')'){
            while(!empty() && gettop() != '('){
                str[i]=gettop();
                j++;
                pop();
            }
            pop();
        }
    }
    while(!empty()){
        str[j]=gettop();
        j++;
        pop();
    }
}

int Evaluate(int t,char y,int r){
    int ty;
    switch(y){
        case '+':
        ty=t+r;
        break;
        case '-':
        ty=r-t;   //I inverted these.
        break;
        case '*':
        ty=r*t;
        break;
        case '/':  //I inverted these because
        ty=r/t;    //even though I did t/r it performed r/t.
        break;     //may be somewhere before the numbers were swapped
        default:
        ty=-1;
        break;
    }
    return ty;
}

int calculatepostfix(char *c){
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(c);i++){
        if(c[i]==' ' || c[i]==','){
            continue;
        }

        else if(isOperator(c[i])){
            int op1=gettop2();
            pop2();
            int op2=gettop2();
            pop2();
            int oper=Evaluate(op1,c[i],op2);
            push2(oper);
        }
        else if(isOperand(c[i])){
            int res=0;
            while(i<strlen(c) && isOperand(c[i])){
                res=(res*10)+(c[i]-'0');
                i++;
            }
            i--;
            push2(res);
        }
    }
    return gettop2();
}

int main(){
    char b[65];
    printf("\n \n**-- Calculator --**\n");
    printf("Enter expression: ");
    fgets(b,sizeof(b),stdin);
    char str[50];
    infToPost(b,str);
    int tt =calculatepostfix(str);
    printf("Your answer is: %d",tt);
}
```

The code in "stackforcalc.h" is

```
#ifndef stacycalc
#define stacycalc
#define maxsize 50

char a[maxsize];
int top=-1;
int abc[maxsize];
int to=-1;

void push2(int re){ abc[++to]=re; }

void push(char b){ a[++top]=b; }

void pop2(){ to--; }

void pop(){ top--;}

int gettop2(){ return (to==-1)?-1:abc[to]; }

char gettop(){ return (top==-1)?0:a[top]; }

int empty(){ return (top==-1)?1:0; }

#endif
```

Comment: Read documentation of your compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) to be used as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/))

Comment: This is where unit tests can help quickly identify faults and steer you towards the actual issues. We're having to do this manually since you've given no hints.

Comment: `int infToPost` doesn't actually `return` an `int`.

Comment: what is unit tests and where and how to read documentation of my compiler? and i know that doesn't return int i did that for testing code purposes.

Comment: could you please answer it in answer section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In infix to postfix function, in place of `str[i]=gettop();`, there should be
`str[j]=gettop()`, so the expression entered inside the brackets can be processed. Also add this piece of code after `fgets` to remove the '\n' that `fgets` may append.

```
fgets(b,sizeof(b),stdin);
for(int i=0;b[i]!='\0';i++){ // removes \n added by fgets
    if(b[i]=='\0'){
        if(b[i-1]=='\n'){
            b[i-1]='\0';
        }
    }
}
```